# Equations with exponents

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation

I can't remember how to solve equations that have exponent and a variable in them. This is somewhat embarrassing, because this used to be really easy for me. I know that logarithms are involved I just can't remember how they are involved. Would anybody be able to help me out? Here is the equation, which needs to be solved for $\alpha$
$$
c_1(e^{-2\alpha - c_2} -\alpha + c_3) = c_4
$$
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you can isolate $\alpha$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This equation does not have solutions that can be expressed in terms of elementary functions. You'd need the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), or solve numerically.

Comment: Thanks. I thought I forgot how to solve these equations.